# database scheme or strategy for openid

Tags: php, database-design, openid, lightopenid

what would be the best strategy to store information about the users openid.
The user must also be able to use different openids, but they have to be linked to the same profile.

*In other words, sort of the same what Stack Overflow does.*

**What should I do?**

For the database sofar, I have openid_url and identity as a field. What would be the unique qualifier for a user-profile. What happens the next time the user decides to login with Yahoo instead of google?

I hope I can get a definitive answer here.

Thanks, Richard

Comment: yes, but what if the user logs in with another openid. Only the uri is enough too, right? I get confused$%#@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create two tables : one containing the user profile (containing a unique profile id, (screen) name, maybe unique login & password for "manual" logins and other user related info like language etc.) and the second just contains a list of all openId profiles linked to a specific user profile (so it should contain at least a profile id from the first table and a URI for the openId - but multiple records for the same profile id should be allowed).

Comment: thank you, you make it sound easy except I forgot to mention that there already is a table with users. I have to ask the user then if he would like to link his openid to his excisting profile. I can work with this, I also found plaxo's guide, but I haven't read it yet.